# I can't do a repository's recovery

Tags: azure-devops, postman

I am trying to do a recovery of one of my repositories on Azure Devops with this URL:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/recycleBin/repositories/{repositoryId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

The problem is when I send it with postman, I get this exception:

```
{
   "$id": "1",
   "innerException": null,
   "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: repositoryDetails",
   "typeName": "System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
   "typeKey": "ArgumentNullException",
   "errorCode": 0,
   "eventId": 0
}
```

Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are **missing the Request Body**:

```
{
   "deleted": false
}
```

> Setting to false will undo earlier deletion and restore the
>   repository.

As described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/restore%20repository%20from%20recycle%20bin?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0